# Dart2's ResizeObserver being broken by Dart minifier

Tags: dart

i have the following snippet of Dart2 code (Dart 2.7) which works 100% when running in dev mode, but fails when running it in production mode

```
  ResizeObserver rowObserver;
```

```
    final ResizeObserverCallback rowObserverCallback = (List<ResizeObserverEntry> entries, ResizeObserver observer){
      print("inside row observer callback");
      for (ResizeObserverEntry entry in entries) {
        print(" ... entry is ${entry.runtimeType} and entry.target is ${entry.target.runtimeType}");
        //resizeRow(entry.target as TableRowElement);
      }
    };

    rowObserver = ResizeObserver(rowObserverCallback);
```

Changing content in the table row now correctly outputs

> inside row observer callback
>
> ... entry is ResizeObserverEntry and entry.target is TableRowElement

When building the Dart code and running it, this same snippet generates the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Instance of 'minified:c1': type 'minified:c1' is
>   not a subtype of type 'List'

Running is done with

```
pub global run webdev serve web:9999
```

While building is done with

```
pub global run webdev build --output=web:build --release
```

i've tried changing --release to --no-release, but not sure how to run it in that mode.

Changing to `dynamic`, i'm getting the exact same issue with minification:

```
final ResizeObserverCallback rowObserverCallback = (dynamic blah1, dynamic blah2){
```

Changing to Object, at least i'm getting into the resize callback:

```
    final ResizeObserverCallback rowObserverCallback = (Object blah1, Object blah2){
      print("inside row observer callback");
      print(blah1.runtimeType);
      print(blah2.runtimeType);
      print(blah1 is List<ResizeObserverEntry>);
```

which outputs:

> inside row observer callback
>
> minified:c1
>
> minified:bQ
>
> false

Force casting it seems to throw a casting error:

```
    final ResizeObserverCallback rowObserverCallback = (Object blah1, Object blah2){
      print("inside row observer callback");
      print(blah1.runtimeType);
      print(blah2.runtimeType);
      print(blah1 is List<ResizeObserverEntry>);

      for (ResizeObserverEntry entry in blah1 as List<ResizeObserverEntry>) {
        print(" ... entry is ${entry.runtimeType} and entry.target is ${entry.target.runtimeType}");
      }
    };
```

> Uncaught CastError: Instance of 'minified:c1': type 'minified:c1' is
>   not a subtype of type 'List'

Force casting it to a single instance of ResizeObserverEntry fails as well

```
    final ResizeObserverCallback rowObserverCallback = (Object blah1, Object blah2){
      print("inside row observer callback");
      print(blah1.runtimeType);
      print(blah2.runtimeType);
      print(blah1 is List<ResizeObserverEntry>);

      for (ResizeObserverEntry entry in [blah1 as ResizeObserverEntry]) {
        print(" ... entry is ${entry.runtimeType} and entry.target is ${entry.target.runtimeType}");
        //resizeRow(entry.target as TableRowElement);
      }
    };
```

> Uncaught CastError: Instance of 'minified:c1': type 'minified:c1' is
>   not a subtype of type 'minified:bp'

pubspec.yaml in case it's relevant:

```
name: blah
version: 0.0.2
description: Blah Blah

environment:
    sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
    angular: ^5.3.1
    angular_forms: ^2.1.2
    http: any
    js: ^0.6.0
    logging: "^0.11.3+1"
    html: any
    json_serializable: any

    blahvo:
        path: ../blah-vo

dev_dependencies:
    angular_test: 2.3.0
    build_runner: ^1.5.2
    build_test: ^0.10.2
    build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
    test: ^1.0.0
```

So how do i actually make ResizeObserver work in Dart2?
It seems ResizeObserver is very broken in Dart2, at least in production / release mode, it works fine in dev mode.

**EDIT1**: 
Some snippets from the generated JS where c1 is referenced:

```
J.c1.prototype={
k:function(a,b){H.p(b,H.j(a,0))
if(!!a.fixed$length)H.a7(P.E("add"))
a.push(b)},
```

```
u.c1=new ResizeObserver(H.aU(new L.j6(),2))},
```

```
this.a.c1.unobserve(a)},
```

```
r.c1.observe(a)},
```

```
if(a.constructor==Array)return J.c1.prototype
```

```
c1:function c1(a){this.$ti=a},
```

```
_.f3=_.c1=_.bg=_.c0=_.f2=null},
```

Trying to shoot in the dark, but not hitting anything

```
    final ResizeObserverCallback rowObserverCallback = (Object blah1, Object blah2){
      print("inside row observer callback");
      print(blah1.runtimeType);
      print(blah2.runtimeType);
      print(blah1 is List<ResizeObserverEntry>);
      print(blah1 is ResizeObserverEntry);
      print(blah1 is TableRowElement);
      print(blah1 is List<TableRowElement>);
      print(blah1 is JsArray);
      print(blah1 is NumToArrayPipe);
      print(blah1 == null);
      print(blah1 is Function);
      print(blah1 is ResizeObserver);
```

all of them prints `false`

Taking a chance and replacing blah1 with blah2

```
    final ResizeObserverCallback rowObserverCallback = (Object blah1, Object blah2){
      print("inside row observer callback");
      print(blah1.runtimeType);
      print(blah2.runtimeType);
      print(blah2 is List<ResizeObserverEntry>);
      print(blah2 is ResizeObserverEntry);
      print(blah2 is TableRowElement);
      print(blah2 is List<TableRowElement>);
      print(blah2 is JsArray);
      print(blah2 is NumToArrayPipe);
      print(blah2 == null);
      print(blah2 is Function);
      print(blah2 is ResizeObserver);
```

and the last one prints true as expected

**EDIT2:**

using JS Interopt, i'm doing `console.log` to see what the type of blah1 actually is and it turns out it is a DartObject containing an Array ...

```
      context["console"].callMethod("log", [blah1]);
```

[image]

What should i cast blah1 to in order to get access to the list of ResizeObserverEntry ?

**EDIT3**

I made a demo that can reproduce the error:
`bug_resize_observer.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="div1" style="background-color: red">
        <textarea style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">
            TESTING
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="background-color: blue">
        .
    </div>
    <script defer src="bug_resize_observer.dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `bug_resize_observer.dart.js`:

```
import "dart:html";

void main() {
  final DivElement div1 = querySelector("div.div1");
  final DivElement div2 = querySelector("div.div2");

  final ResizeObserver divResizeObserver = ResizeObserver((List<ResizeObserverEntry> blah1, ResizeObserver blah2) {
    print("inside divResizeObserverCallback");
    for (ResizeObserverEntry entry in blah1) {
        div2.style.height = "${entry.target.clientHeight}px";
    }
  });
  divResizeObserver.observe(div1);
}
```

In DEV mode, the blue div mimicks the height of the red div when you resize the text area:

[image]

In release mode, you only get errors:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT4:**

Logged a bug here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40961

Comment: ResizeObserver issue fixed in 2.8.dev-13, ResizeObserverEntry stil broken:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40975